# Bug: Google Drive Picker stopped loading today

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, picker

Have been using Drive Picker successfully in our app for almost a year now. A few weeks ago had an issue with the picker which prompted an upgrade to the latest JS api. Things were working fine since until this morning. Now the picker won't load, and I receive the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Incorrect origin value. Please set it to - (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) of the top-most page 1610138292-picker_modularized_opc.js:821
RT 1610138292-picker_modularized_opc.js:821
_createPicker 1610138292-picker_modularized_opc.js:823
```

Anybody run into this before? This seems to be an error inside the internal picker JS. I tried debugging myself to see what's going on but the minimized Javascript is too painful.

Comment: What are those two lines? (821 and 823) Just a dump of a few lines works as well, if you can't pick out the exact lines in minified code.

Comment: So... What is the question?

Comment: Google did have a lot of problems with it's platform today and drive I think was one of the services affected that may have been your problem.

Comment: Is it working now? Was the issue a result of the services being down?

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive was down for awhile today. Same with Google chat and some of their other services. Might be causing you to see this issue.